# Docker connectivity issues (to Azure DevOps Services from self hosted Linux Docker agent)

Tags: docker, hyper-v, docker-for-windows, docker-network, git-lfs

I am looking for some advice on debugging some extremely painful Docker connectivity issues.

In particular, for an Azure DevOps Services Git repository, I am running a self-hosted (locally) dockerized Linux CI (setup according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#linux), which has been working fine for a few months now.

All this runs on a company network, and since last week the network connection of my docker container became highly unstable:

- Specifically it intermittently looses network connection, which is also visible via the logs of the Azure DevOps agent, which then keeps trying to reconnect.
- This especially happens while downloading Git LFS objects. Enabling extra traces via GIT_TRACE=1 highlights a lot of connection failures and retries:

  > trace git-lfs: xfer: failed to resume download for "SHA" from byte N: expected status code 206, received 200. Re-downloading from start
- During such a LFS pull / fetch, sometimes the container even stops responding as a `docker container list` command only responds:

  > Error response from daemon: i/o timeout

  As a result the daemon cannot recover on its own, and needs a manual restart (to get back up the CI).

Also I see remarkable differences in network performance:

- Manually cloning the same Git repository (including LFS objects, all from scratch) in **container instances (created from the same image) on different machines**, takes less than 2mins on my dev laptop machine (connected from home via VPN), while the same operation **easily takes up to 20minutes (!) on containers running two different Win10 machines** (company network, physically located in offices, hence no VPN.
- Clearly this is not about the host network connection itself, since cloning on the same Win10 hosts (company network/offices) outside of the containers takes only 14seconds!

Hence I am suspecting some network configuration issues (e.g. sth with the Hyper-V vEthernet Adapter? Firewall? Proxy? or whichever other watchdog going astray?), but after three days of debugging, I am not quite sure how to further investigate this issue, as I am running out of ideas and expertise. Any thoughts / advice / hints?

I should add that LFS configuration options ([such as lfs.concurrenttransfers and lfs.basictransfersonly](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-config.5.ronn#transfer-upload--download-settings)) did not really help, similarly for [git config http.version](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpversion) (or just removing some larger files)

---

### ***UPDATE***

it does not actually seem to be about the self-hosted agent but a more general docker network cfg issue within my corporate network.

Running the following works consistently fast on my VPN machine (running from home):

```
docker run -it
ubuntu bash -c "apt-get update; apt-get install -y wget; start=$SECONDS;
wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04-alternate-amd64.iso;
echo Duration: $(( SECONDS - start )) seconds"
```

Comparision with powershell download (on the host):

```
$start=Get-Date
$(New-Object
net.webclient).Downloadfile("http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04-alternate-amd64.iso",
"e:/temp/lubuntu-18.04-alternate-amd64.iso")
'Duration: {0:mm}
min {0:ss} sec' -f ($(Get-Date)-$start)
```

***Corporate network***

- Docker: 1560 seconds (=26 min!)
- Windows host sys: Duration: 00 min 15 sec

***Dev laptop (VPN, from home):***

- Docker: 144 seconds (=2min 24sec)
- Windows host sys: Duration: 02 min 16 sec

Looking at the issues discussed in https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/698 (and proposed workaround which didn't work for me), it seems to be a non-trivial problem with Windows / hyper-v ..

Comment: Could you create a new self-hosted agent and try it again, then share the result here?

Comment: it does not actually seem to be about the self-hosted agent but a more general docker network issue within my corporate network. - see update above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole issue "solved itself" when my company decided to finally upgrade from Win10 1803 to 1909 (which comes with WSL, replacing Hyper-V) .. 
Now everything runs supersmoothly (I kept running these tests for almost 20 times)